# Multithreaded udp server

Tags: c, multithreading, udp

I'm new with threads and please if you can advice me. I have server that broadcast messages
to clients. Then clients sends back replies to server. I want to handle every reply using
seperate thread. Every reply will have mesage id and thread id. How can I fill some structure
with this information from all threads and then read it

Also from my code, is it correctly to create thread in while or does it exist someway
to create thread just if I get reply from client?

Did I start with correct understanding?

```
int main(){

    while(1){

        sendto on broadcast IP 
        pthread_create(&cln_thread, NULL, msg_processing, (void *) &arg))

   }
}

msg_processing () {

     recvfrom client msg with id of packet and thread id
     how to write those informations and then read them in main when program finish

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Err.. no, just create ONE thread, once only, for receiving datagrams on one socket.  In the thread function, receive the datagrams in a while(true) loop. Don't let this receive thread terminate and don't create any more receive threads. Continually creating/terminating/destroying threads is inefficient, dangerous, unnecessary, error-prone, difficult-to-debug and you should try very hard to not do it, ever.

Edit:

One receive thread only - but you don't have to do the processing there.  Malloc a 64K buffer, receive data into it, push the buffer pointer onto a producer-consumer queue to a pool of threads that will do the processing, loop back and so malloc again to reseat the pointer and create another buffer for the next datagram.  Free the *buffers in the pool threads after the processing is completed.  The receive thread will be back waiting for datagrams quickly while the buffer processing runs concurrently.

If you find that the datagrams can arrive so rapidly that the processing cannot keep up, memory use will grow unchecked as more and more *buffers pile up in the queue. There are a couple ways round that.  You can use a bounded queue that blocks if its capacity is reached.   You could create x buffers at startup and store them on another producer-consumer 'pool queue' that the receive thread pops from, (instead of the malloc) - the processing pool threads can then push the 'used' *buffers back on to the pool queue for re-use.  If the pool runs out, the receive thread will block on the pool until *buffers are returned.

I prefer the pooled-buffer approach since it caps memory-use across the whole system, avoids continual malloc/free with its fragmentation issues etc, avoids the more complex bounded queues, is easier to tweak, (the pool level is easy to change at runtime), and is easier to monitor/debug - I usually dump the pool level, (ie. queue count), to the display once a second with a timer.

In either case, datagrams may be lost but, if your system is overloaded such that data regularly arrives faster than it can possibly be processed,  that's going to be the case anyway no matter how you design it.

One socket is fine, so why complicate matters?  :)

Comment: Ok, I understood. But this application will be in real time, so I was wondering is one thread enough to process all replies from client? And is one socket enough for sending and receiving or shooul I create two different sockets ? Thanks

Comment: Dear Martin, I'm not so good in programming especially with this thing that I'm new with ...So I don't understand a half of yours explanation :) First, in the above code I create more threads in a while loop, I receive data in buffer which I memset to 0 after read what I'm interested in...Another thing, If I create one thread before while, and then in while just call function msg_proccesing then I'm not able to receive nothing from clients so I don't understand how to make it with one thread

Comment: Then try something simpler first!

Comment: Can you help me with one thread implementation? As I said when I create just one thread and then call the function server doesn't receiving replies...

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example of a multithreaded UDP server in Go lang following:
https://gist.github.com/jtblin/18df559cf14438223f93

The main idea is to use multi-core functionality in a full so each thread works on its own CPU core and reads UDP data into the single buffer for processing.