# Handling packets received from multiple clients to multiple threads in c

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, udp

when multiple clients send packets to server how can i write code to receive them on their corresponding child threads instead of receiving them on main process

i am writing c program for udp client and server using threads so if i have 4 clients connected 4 threads will be created and each thread will send some data. after receiving the data the clients will send acks but the problem is those acks should be received by the corresponding threads but

i have receivefrom function in main process to listen for new clients and i also have receivefrom function on threads to get ack packets but these ack coming from client are going to main process instead of coming to threads please help me thanks in advance

my code
server code

```
//created udp socket

// binded

while(1)
{
    // to receive new connections 
    n=recvfrom(sock,buffer,512,0,(struct sockaddr*)&from,&length);  

    // if some client sent request i will assign new thread to serve it
    pthread_create(&thread_id[str_cnt], NULL, serve,(void*)(&cli[str_cnt])); 
}

function serve(args)
{

    while(1)
    {   
        // sendind data to that client
        sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr,clientlen);

        //now wating for ack from the client
        sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr,clientlen);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you show us the code, it would be easier to suggest what you need.

Comment: @Gerhardh please help me

Comment: Packets are received from that recv from() in main function instead of getting from recvfrom()  function on threads

Comment: These are rather incomplete snippets. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Typically threads are used in such a scenario to read on a connection from a client. With UDP you do not have a connection and cannot read in a thread as all client data is received on the same socket.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't have multiple threads reading from the same socket at the
>   same time.
>
> What you should do instead is either:
>
> 1. have a dedicated thread that receives all inbound packets, looks at the source IP/Port, and routes the data to the appropriate processing
>      thread as needed.
> 2. give each processing thread its own socket that is `bind()`'ed to the same local IP/Port and `connect()`'ed to the particular source
>      IP/Port it is interested in, then each thread can call `recvfrom()`
>      independently and it will only return packets that match the source
>      that the thread is expecting.

I took this from **Remy Lebeau** on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387873/udp-server-how-can-do-that-each-thread-will-receive-the-right-clients-packet-a).

UDP doesn't have a notion of separate connections unless you use different ports and handle them yourself, that's why they created TCP (and also for more reliable, in-order communication.)  You're already emulating reliable communication by using ACKs, so the only overhead is in-order communication (and checksums, if you don't like them either) so you might be better off using TCP.